# How to write a regex that removes everything after $_POST['some_string']

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
string = '$_POST["a_string_of_unspecified_length"][4]input&set1';
```

How to write a regex that will return only  `$_POST["a_string_of_unspecified-length"]` and discard everything after the first set of brackets

```
$string_afer_regex = '$_POST["a_string_of_unspecified_length"]'
```

Comment: Can you people stop downvoting questions without posting an explanation! This behavior doesn't help anyone.

Comment: The voting system has  always been anonymous. There are a number of threads on [meta] about it. Start with [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312633/should-downvotes-no-longer-be-anonymous). One of the reasons it's anonymous is that it avoids flame wars erupting in the comments.

Comment: I imagine your question is being downvoted because it's not clear why you'd want to do what you're asking - i.e editing PHP code with a Regex. It looks like an [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Then stackoverflow should implement a feature where someone can downvote and post an anonymous explanation. It is a simple fix.

Comment: That's been [discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367424/add-anonymous-comments-for-answer-downvotes) on  [meta] too, but you could raise it again there if you wish. The comments here aren't the place to discuss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regex `^\$_POST\[[^]]+\]`

```
$str = '$_POST["a_string_of_unspecified_length"][4]input&set1';
preg_match('~^\$_POST\[[^]]+\]~', $str, $matches);
print_R($matches);
// $_POST["a_string_of_unspecified_length"]

^     - beginning of string
\$    - escaped dollar sign
_POST - normal characters, just part of string
\[    - escaped '['
[^]]+ - everything till ']', + means 'more than 1 character'
\]    - escaped '['
the rest doesn't care us, there can be whatever
```

Without regex, if needed

```
$str = '$_POST["a_string_of_unspecified_length"][4]input&set1';
echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str, ']') + 1);
// $_POST["a_string_of_unspecified_length"]
```

Comment: @Jimski: added little explanation

Comment: Very cool, I would upvote your answer again but stackoverflow allows only one upvote per questions.